# Cannot get cookie value

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, cookies

I have a script that calls a prompt when I push a button and gets a number from the user. The number is stored in a cookie. Then that script loads a view that gets the number from the cookie and passes it to a form.

Currently I have the cookie being saved; I can see it in the browser debugger. But when I try to get the cookie in my view it always returns null.

I think the request sends a cookie with a null value before updating the cookie.

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).off('click', '.order_button').on('click', '.order_button', function() {
        // $(".on_button").click(function() {
        var amount = prompt("Please enter amount of orders" ,"0")
        if (parseInt(amount) <= 0 /* || amount === null */) {
            alert("Please enter integer greater than 0")
        } else if (parseInt(amount) > 0) {
            document.cookie = "amount=" + amount; //+ ";max-age=60";
            console.log(document.cookie)
            var link = $(this).find('a');
            console.log(link.attr('href'));
            window.location.href=link.attr('href');
            console.log("OK");
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

View

```
def add_order(request, meal_slug, meal_restaurant):
    print("OK")
    amount = get_server_side_cookie(request, 'amount', '1')
    print(amount)
    //clear_amount_cookie(request)
    if amount is not None:
        meal = Meal.objects.get(
            slug=meal_slug, restaurant_slug=meal_restaurant)
        user = UserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
        order = Order.objects.create(
            meal=meal, customer=user, amount=amount, date=datetime.now())
        order.save()
        //clear_amount_cookie(request)
    return redirect('food_cloud:index')
```

Get cookie function

```
def get_server_side_cookie(request, cookie, default_val=None):
    val = request.COOKIES.get(cookie)
    print(val) //This is where I see the null value
    try:
        int(val)
    except (ValueError, TypeError):
        val = default_val
        print(val + " here")
    return val
```

Comment: Can you try checking if the cookie was actually sent? In Chrome network tab, you can intercept HTTP requests to your server. Look at the request that you are generating and try to locate the `Cookie` header. What are its contents?

Comment: I just checked that and the 'amount' cookie sent was 'null'. Could it be that the request is being sent before the cookie is updated?

Comment: Means your problem is most definitely on the JS side. You put in a `console.log(document.cookie)`. What does it say?

Comment: When I run it as it is, it doesn't say anything I guess because the page gets refreshed by the link call. But when I comment out the link call it shows that  'amount' has the value I assigned it using the prompt.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by implementing the jquery.cookies.js objects Link: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Then I replaced the code for creating the cookie. Apparently JQuery is not good for handling cookies directly

Changed code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).off('click', '.order_button').on('click', '.order_button', function() {
        var amount = prompt("Please enter amount of orders" ,"0");
        if (parseInt(amount) <= 0 /* || amount === null */) {
            alert("Please enter integer greater than 0")
        } else if (parseInt(amount) > 0) {
            Cookies.set('amount', amount) //This is the new code for creating cookie
            console.log(document.cookie)
            var link = $(this).find('a');
            console.log(link.attr('href'));
            window.location.href=link.attr('href');
            console.log("OK");
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```